# UITableView with dynamic row height shows Auto Layout constraint errors

Tags: ios, uitableview, autolayout

I am creating a table view having cells whose height is determined by Auto Layout.

The table view cell has only one subview - An `UIImageView` which is pinned to the 4 sides of the table view cell.
The image view has a constraint to maintain aspect ratio of `4:3`.

The following image shows the view hierarchy and constraints.
[image: image showing view hierarchy and constraints]

The height of the row of the table view is set to automatic as the following screenshot shows.
[image]

When the app is run, the table view cell looks as expected, but the following Auto Layout constraint errors are shown in the logs

```
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600001d804b0 AppName.NeverClearImageView:0x7f938ce140f0.width == 1.33333*AppName.NeverClearImageView:0x7f938ce140f0.height   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600001d80460 AppName.NeverClearImageView:0x7f938ce140f0.bottom == UITableViewCellContentView:0x7f938ce04790.bottom   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600001d80410 H:[AppName.NeverClearImageView:0x7f938ce140f0]-(0)-|   (active, names: '|':UITableViewCellContentView:0x7f938ce04790 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600001d82a80 H:|-(0)-[AppName.NeverClearImageView:0x7f938ce140f0]   (active, names: '|':UITableViewCellContentView:0x7f938ce04790 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600001d82bc0 V:|-(0)-[AppName.NeverClearImageView:0x7f938ce140f0]   (active, names: '|':UITableViewCellContentView:0x7f938ce04790 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600001dbb930 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Height' UITableViewCellContentView:0x7f938ce04790.height == 125.5   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600001db8dc0 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Width' UITableViewCellContentView:0x7f938ce04790.width == 256   (active)>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600001d804b0 AppName.NeverClearImageView:0x7f938ce140f0.width == 1.33333*AppName.NeverClearImageView:0x7f938ce140f0.height   (active)>
```

The table view cell looks as expected. Can anyone point out how to resolve this error?

Note - I observe that the above error is not shown if the priority of the aspect ratio is set to 999 instead of 1000. Can anyone point out why this solves the issue?

Comment: you cannot maintain aspect ratio constraint when you pin image view to edges. Either remove bottom-trailing or remove aspect constraint ./

Comment: This is common when using proportional constraints. It seems that auto-layout doesn't like values that are not multiples of `0.5`. It *works*, but (apparently) auto-layout throws the warning / error messages. There are a number of related cases, particularly when using stack views, and when using Trait variations. As you note, changing the Priority to `999` solves it.

Comment: Another possible explanation (I don't know the down-and-dirty details). I believe auto-layout makes more than "one pass." It's very possible that it finds the conflict, prints the error to the debug console, and then "fixes up" the constraints. That would explain getting these messages, even though the end-result is laid-out as expected.